# $\int \frac {4}{7\sqrt {5x-6}}dx$

Tags: integration

Why can't I use the substitution

$$u=\sqrt {5x-6}$$
$$u^2=5x-6$$
$$2udu=5dx$$
$$dx=\frac {2u}{5}du$$
$$\int\frac {4}{7u}\cdot \frac {2u}{5}du=\int \frac {8u}{35u}du=\int \frac {8}{35}du=\frac {8}{35}+C$$

The answer is obviously incorrect, but what have I done wrong?

Comment: You haven't actually integrated at the last step.

Comment: Problem is $\int {\rm d}u = u + c$

Comment: But the u's cancel out right?

Comment: As an aside, a simpler substitution would be $u = 5x-6$. So you would then compute $\frac{4}{7 \cdot 5} \int u^{-1/2} du$.

Comment: Yeah, that was my first thought but was wondering about the other option to remove the square root. The substitution that I used is easier in my opinion though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that 
$$\int dx=x+K$$
So we have that:

$$I=\int\frac {4}{7u}\cdot \frac {2u}{5}du=\frac 8{35}u+K$$
$$I=\frac 8{35}\sqrt {5x-6}+K$$

Comment: Thanks! I see the mistake

Comment: @Stallmp yw... ...you did a good job just correct the last step

Answer (score 2):

$$\int\frac {4}{7u}\cdot \frac {2u}{5}du = \int \frac{8}{35} du =\frac{8}{35} \color{red}{u} + C = \frac{8}{35} \sqrt{5x-6} + C$$

Comment: Thanks! I see the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I would Substitute $$t=5x-6$$ then is $$x=\frac{t+6}{5}$$ and $$dx=\frac{1}{5}dt$$
The right result is given by $$\frac{8}{35} \sqrt{5 x-6}+C$$

Comment: Yeah, that was my first thought but was wondering about the other option to remove the square root. The substitution that I used is easier in my opinion though.

Comment: ok the main Thing is that your Problem is solved now!

Answer (score 0):

$$\int {4\over 7\sqrt{5x-6}}\mathrm dx\tag1$$

Let $u=5x-6$ then ${du\over dx}=4$, write as $dx={1\over 5}du$

Rewrite $(1)$ in term of $u$

$${4\over 35}\int {\mathrm du\over \sqrt{u}}={4\over 35}\int u^{-1/2}\mathrm du={4\over 35}{u^{-1/2+1}\over -1/2+1}+c={8\over 35}u^{1/2}+c\tag2$$

Rewrite the $(2)$ in term of $x$

$$\int {4\over 7\sqrt{5x-6}}\mathrm dx={8\over 35}\sqrt{5x+6}+c\tag3$$